# Azure Service Bus alternative to transactional outbox pattern

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, transactions, azureservicebus, consistency

Let's say I have this generic saga scenario (given three distinct microservices A, B, and C, communicating with messaging):

```
 1. Service A
    a. Performs operation A successfully
    b. Communicates update with message A
 2. Service B (after receiving message A)
    a. Performs operation B successfully
    b. Communicates update with message B
 3. Service C (after receiving message B)
    a. Fails to perform operation B
    b. Communicates failure
 4. Service A and B performs compensating actions
```

It is my understanding that while the entire workflow should be eventually consistent, you want to ensure that the local operations (the `a` and `b`) are transactionally consistent to avoid losing messages (or if reverse, avoid sending messages but fail to persist operation changes).

This is the problem that the [transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) aims to solve, if I'm not mistaken.

In the context of .NET on Azure, using

- EF Core
- Azure Service Bus

**Is there a way to get the same level of transactional security without saving the message to the database (i.e. not using a transactional outbox)?**

I've seen a lot of [System.Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions) mentions, but it's either being used for multiple database operations *or* multiple service bus operations, not database and service bus operations *together*.

Could something like this achieve the desired transactional consistency?

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    // _dbContext.Database.EnlistTransaction(ts); <-- ?
    _dbContext.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet" });
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    await _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage());
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Service Bus supports transactions only in the scope of its own operations and serves as its own coordinator with its own rules for those transactions.  It does not integrate with other distributed transaction coordinators and won't participate in a transaction with a database or other message broker.    _(for more context, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions)_

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks for enlightening me and yanking me out of the rabbit hole! I guess I was hoping for less work and less complexity, but at least there seem to be libraries that can help with transactional outboxes, like CAP or NServiceBus.

Comment: Unfortunately, when it comes to distributed systems, managing state consistency often requires complexity.   This is a case where you'd often see the [saga pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga) applied.

Comment: You could look into using NServiceBus outbox with the ASB transport. The outbox could be either a relational or document datsbase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't achieve that as different resources cannot participate in a single transaction as that would become a distributed transaction, which is undesired in a cloud environment.

To ensure your data and messaging operations share the same transaction, you'd be looking into some sort of persistence such as outbox.

Frameworks such as NServiceBus provide support for outbox with Azure Service Bus as a transport and SQL Server or document database as a data store.

Comment: There seems to be a couple of patterns that technically doesn't have you store the message to the database: Transaction log tailing, and event state capture(?). A transactional outbox seems to be the best fit for me though.

Comment: In that case this link could be helpful: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/